# Ubuntu 17.04 after resume VPN is lost, synclient resets, and cursor freezes for 15 seconds

Tags: suspend, 17.04, synaptics

Laptop: Samsung NP900X5N-X01US

Ubuntu Version: 17.04-20

Shell: Gnome

- When resuming from sleep, the cursor freezes for about 15 seconds and sometimes even the keyboard locks up during that period.
- Additionally, my synclient config that i have run on startup is lost so I have to rerun it.
- I also have to reconnect my VPN, but that may be working as intended. I mention this because it seems like there is a lot going on with the WiFi in the syslogs.

Syslog output (first 3 lines are pre-sleep, the rest is after i wake it up. Sometimes, the cursor freezes immediately upon wake, other times it act normal for up to 5 seconds and then lock up.

Syslog is here (I'd post it inline, but it exceeds the length): https://pastebin.com/gRimpHS1

Lines that look questionable to my noob eyes:

```
systemd-sleep[1792]: /lib/systemd/system-sleep/wpasupplicant failed with error code 254.
kernel: [10863.016958] ACPI : EC: event blocked
kernel: [10863.570877] rtc_cmos 00:01: System wakeup disabled by ACPI
systemd-sleep[1913]: /lib/systemd/system-sleep/wpasupplicant failed with error code 255.
kernel: [10877.031266] [drm:intel_pipe_update_end [i915]] *ERROR* Atomic update failure on pipe A (start=760 end=761) time 324 us, min 1073, max 1079, scanline start 1060, end 1089
kernel: [10883.899298] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Queue 10 stuck for 10000 ms.
```

Any ideas on what could be locking the system up?